# Search all OU's within a domain in the AD to find a user

Tags: active-directory, spring-ldap

I have set up the LDAP properties pointing to a base DN of `OU=IT, DC=test, DC=co, DC=uk` in my Java web application. Everyone from that group can now access using the AD account name and password fine.

However, the administrators have configured AD in such a way that all users are not in one OU.
They have split the users into seperate OU's ie.
say the domain is `test.co.uk`

Some agents are in say `OU=IT, DC=test, DC=co, DC=uk`
Some agents are in say `OU=Glasgow, DC=test, DC=co, DC=uk`
Some agents are in say `OU=Edinburgh, DC=test, DC=co, DC=uk`
Some agents are in say `OU=London, DC=test, DC=co, DC=uk`

Is it possible to search ALL OU's within the domain in the AD to find the user?
As we require all users to have access.

I tried with base DN as `DC=test, DC=co, DC=uk`. It wouldn't work. The AD is   maintained by my client. If the base DN I tried should work and isn't working, What could be the possible reasons? Does that have anything to do with the permissions we have on client AD?